# PHP convert date interval diff to decimal

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

I'm trying to convert the difference between two dates into a total year count, right now I'm using this:

```
 $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11'); 
 $datetime2 = new DateTime('2010-10-10');
 $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
 return $interval->format('%y');
```

This returns me an int (Like 0 for < than a year, 2 for two years, etc.)

I need the result to be decimal as following:

0.9 - 9 months

1.2 - 1 year and two months

3.5 - 3 years and five months

and so on..

Thanks!

Comment: What would it look like with 11 months?

Comment: Well, I feel pretty stupid right now... I have no idea.. Maybe process the result to round up if decimal >= 10? I don't need that much accuracy.

Comment: Well the answer posted by @Matthew covers both cases. If you, strangely, want 11 months to be 0.11, then following his bottom example. If you want it to be something very close to 1, ~0.93, then follow the top example. That however will lose your nice 9 months = 0.9, where 9 months will become 0.75. This will make more sense mathematically, which is what I recommend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't care about perfect accuracy:

```
return $interval->days / 365;
```

You could also do something like `return $interval->y + $interval->m / 12 + $interval->d / 365`.

Didn't even notice your weird decimal convention until I saw @2unco's comment. That would look like: `return $interval->y . '.' . $interval->m`.

Comment: Fantastic, the $interval->y . '.' . $interval->m made it. Somehow it's weird but that's what I need right now, thank you very much Matthew!

Answer (score 2):

Here you can see a function that does exactly that and with many options: 
http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-diff.php#98615

```
    <?php 
/* 
* A mathematical decimal difference between two informed dates 
*
* Author: Sergio Abreu
* Website: http://sites.sitesbr.net
*
* Features: 
* Automatic conversion on dates informed as string.
* Possibility of absolute values (always +) or relative (-/+)
*/

function s_datediff( $str_interval, $dt_menor, $dt_maior, $relative=false){

       if( is_string( $dt_menor)) $dt_menor = date_create( $dt_menor);
       if( is_string( $dt_maior)) $dt_maior = date_create( $dt_maior);

       $diff = date_diff( $dt_menor, $dt_maior, ! $relative);

       switch( $str_interval){
           case "y": 
               $total = $diff->y + $diff->m / 12 + $diff->d / 365.25; break;
           case "m":
               $total= $diff->y * 12 + $diff->m + $diff->d/30 + $diff->h / 24;
               break;
           case "d":
               $total = $diff->y * 365.25 + $diff->m * 30 + $diff->d + $diff->h/24 + $diff->i / 60;
               break;
           case "h": 
               $total = ($diff->y * 365.25 + $diff->m * 30 + $diff->d) * 24 + $diff->h + $diff->i/60;
               break;
           case "i": 
               $total = (($diff->y * 365.25 + $diff->m * 30 + $diff->d) * 24 + $diff->h) * 60 + $diff->i + $diff->s/60;
               break;
           case "s": 
               $total = ((($diff->y * 365.25 + $diff->m * 30 + $diff->d) * 24 + $diff->h) * 60 + $diff->i)*60 + $diff->s;
               break;
          }
       if( $diff->invert)
               return -1 * $total;
       else    return $total;
   }

/* Enjoy and feedback me ;-) */
?>
```

Comment: Not quite exact with regard to years and months. It would be better to use $diff->days instead of $diff->y * 365.25 + $diff->m*30 + $diff->d

Comment: Your days (case "d") is incorrect.  Minutes are for an hour calc not a days cal.  the last part should be $diff->i / 1440.  Note 1440 is 24*60

Answer (score 1):

Simpler and more accurate interval converter to days/hours/minutes/seconds:

```
function DateDiffInterval($sDate1, $sDate2, $sUnit='H') {
//subtract $sDate2-$sDate1 and return the difference in $sUnit (Days,Hours,Minutes,Seconds)
    $nInterval = strtotime($sDate2) - strtotime($sDate1);
    if ($sUnit=='D') { // days
        $nInterval = $nInterval/60/60/24;
    } else if ($sUnit=='H') { // hours
        $nInterval = $nInterval/60/60;
    } else if ($sUnit=='M') { // minutes
        $nInterval = $nInterval/60;
    } else if ($sUnit=='S') { // seconds
    }
    return $nInterval;
} //DateDiffInterval
```