# PHP - Find the difference between two times

Tags: php

I'm trying to calculate the time difference (in hours) between two times inputted via a timepicker. I have working JavaScript code, but would rather use server side code to make this calculation as it's quite important. If you want me to post the working JS code let me know in comments.

Calculating the difference between the times is easy enough, but I require the output in a particular format. For example inputs of '07:30' and '14:00' would return 6.5 rather than 6.3. The reason for this is to make it easier for me to use this time difference in calculations.

PHP Code i've tried:

Attempt #1:

```
<?php
$start_time = new DateTime('07:30');
$end_time = new DateTime('14:00');
$time_diff = date_diff($start_time,$end_time);

echo $time_diff->format('%h.%i');
?>
```

Returns 6.3 as expected.

Attempt #2:

```
<?php
$start_time = "07:30";
$end_time = "14:00";
$start_time = str_replace(":", "", $start_time);
$end_time = str_replace(":", "", $end_time);
$res = $end_time - $start_time;
$result = $res / 100;
echo $result;
?>
```

Returns 6.7.

Tool used to test output: http://codepad.viper-7.com/

Comment: Are you asking to have minutes and seconds returned as fractional hours?

Comment: @Floris correct, minus the seconds part.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778338/php-convert-date-interval-diff-to-decimal

Comment: Hours plus minutes/60

Comment: @Floris Thanks for the help, math is not my strong point but I fully understand the calculation required now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the minutes:

```
<?php
$start_time = new DateTime('07:30');
$end_time = new DateTime('14:00');
$time_diff = date_diff($start_time,$end_time);

$hours = (int)$time_diff->format('%h');
$hour_part =  ((int)$time_diff->format('%i')) / 60;
echo $hours + $hour_part;
?>
```

Make sure to change the type to `(int)` before any calculations.
If you divide the minutes by 60 you will get what part of a hour they represent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer d.raev, I will accept your answer once the timer permits it. I would also +1 but I lack the reputation required.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $start_time = new DateTime('07:30');
    $end_time = new DateTime('14:00');

    $time_diff = date_diff($start_time,$end_time);

    echo $time_diff->format('%h') + $time_diff->format('%i')/60;
?>
```

Returns 6.5 as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very simple and elegant. However I have to accept d.raev's answer as he was slightly faster. I would give you a +1 but I lack the reputation.

Comment: @Danieloplata you can accept whichever answer you want - no obligation to accept "the first". Go get some reputation so you can upvote answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php
$start_time = strtotime("07:30");
$end_time = strtotime("14:00");

$diff = $end_time - $start_time;

echo $diff;
```

Comment: Returns output: 23400 - possibly converting to seconds?

Comment: echo date('H:i', strtotime($diff)); Using this method to convert second to time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get the time difference between two times:

```
function timeBetween($start_date,$end_date)   
  {   

    $diff = $end_date-$start_date;   
    $seconds = 0;   
    $hours   = 0;   
    $minutes = 0;   
    if($diff % 86400 <= 0){$days = $diff / 86400;}  // 86,400 seconds in a day   

    if($diff % 86400 > 0)   
    {   
        $rest = ($diff % 86400);   
        $days = ($diff - $rest) / 86400;   
        if($rest % 3600 > 0)   
        {   
            $rest1 = ($rest % 3600);   
            $hours = ($rest - $rest1) / 3600;   
            if($rest1 % 60 > 0)   
            {   
                $rest2 = ($rest1 % 60);   
            $minutes = ($rest1 - $rest2) / 60;   
            $seconds = $rest2;   
            }   
            else{$minutes = $rest1 / 60;}   
        }   
        else{$hours = $rest / 3600;}   
    }   

    if($days > 0){$days = $days.' days, ';}   
    else{$days = false;}   
    if($hours > 0){$hours = $hours.' hours, ';}   
    else{$hours = false;}   
    if($minutes > 0){$minutes = $minutes.' minutes, ';}   
    else{$minutes = false;}   
    $seconds = $seconds.' seconds';

    return $days.''.$hours.''.$minutes.''.$seconds;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 hour = 60 min.
[Demo.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/26cd62d19b6a2782420185b7d6614d9d2d1aa896)

```
$start_time = "07:30";
$end_time = "14:00";
list($h1, $m1) = explode(':', $start_time);
list($h2, $m2) = explode(':', $end_time);
// 1 hr = 60 min
$res = ($h2*60 - $m2) - ($h1*60 + $m1);
$result = floor($res/60) .'.'. $res % 60;
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

function time_difference($time1, $time2) {

```
$time1 = strtotime("1980-01-01 $time1");
$time2 = strtotime("1980-01-01 $time2");

if ($time2 < $time1) {
    $time2 += 86400;
}
```

return date("H:i:s", strtotime("1980-01-01 00:00:00") + ($time2 - $time1));
}

echo time_difference("11:30:30", "22:40:59");