# PHP Date : get date different in years

Tags: php, date, phpexcel

this is my code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$date_join = $row['date_joined']; =produce 2012-09-03
$today = date("Y-m-d");   = produce 2014-08-29

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('H'.$a, **$xxx**);
```

how can i get date durations ($today - $date_join) in years like :

Date of services : 1.5 years

Comment: this should shed some light. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778338/php-convert-date-interval-diff-to-decimal)

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php to calculate the difference in days, then convert to years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PHP strtotime() function`. Try like this..

```
$join_date = '2012-09-03'; //join date
$today = date("Y-m-d"); //current date

$date_join  = strtotime($join_date); // join date to seconds
$today = strtotime($today); //current date to seconds

$differenceInSeconds = $today - $date_join; // Time difference in seconds
echo number_format($differenceInSeconds / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60), 2) . ' Year(s)';
```

- Get time difference in seconds from two dates
- Divide the difference by one year equivalent seconds