# calculate how many years and months between two month and year in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to calculate the difference between two month and year. My input for calculating month and year is

```
$fromYear = 2016;
$fromMonth = 3;
$toYear = 2018;
$toMonth = 9;
```

And i want a output like **2 years, 6 months** or **2.5 years**. Im using laravel for develope my application. I want to achieve this through **carbon** or default **php** function. Kindly help me in this.

Comment: Have you looked at the `date_diff()` function? https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_diff.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Date : get date different in years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560987/php-date-get-date-different-in-years)

Comment: You need first from those 2 dates to make Carbon dates, after that he will the the job i, here it is the seciton of the docts https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

Comment: @RichardMatheson But i dont know how to calculate because i have month and years seperately

Comment: 2 years 6 months is not 2.6 years, it's 2.5 years.

Comment: @JamesZ Oops! You are right.. thanks for your info :)

Answer (score 3):

Make 2 carbon instances like that

```
$year = 2000; $month = 4; $day = 19
$hour = 20; $minute = 30; $second = 15; $tz = 'Europe/Madrid';
$date = Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, $day, $tz);
$date->diffForHumans($secondDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help -

```
$fromYear = 2016;
$fromMonth = 3;
$toYear = 2018;
$toMonth = 9;

$datetime1 = date_create($fromYear . '-' . $fromMonth . '-01');// Concatenate & consider date starts from 1st
$datetime2 = date_create($toYear . '-' . $toMonth . '-01');

$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

var_dump($interval->y . ' years, ' . $interval->m . ' months');
```

[Code](https://eval.in/1069664)

**O/P**

```
string(17) "2 years, 6 months"
```

Need to add proper checks if required.

Comment: It helps me a lot.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with Carbon it can help you with date validation as well.

```
$fromYear = 2016;
$fromMonth = 3;
$toYear = 2018;
$toMonth = 9;

$from = Carbon::parse($fromYear.'-'.$fromMonth);
$to = Carbon::parse($toYear.'-'.$toMonth);
$diff = $from->diffForHumans($to, true, false, 6);

"2 years 6 months"
```